# Laravel 9: Media folders not opening with SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl

I need help with this:

I have installed letsencrypt to my Laravel 9 application. On the front end, the images are loading correctly over http and https domains.

With https, I cannot upload the images on the backend. However, I am able to upload images on the backend with http domain.
[HTTP upload folder] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXKcS.jpg)]
[https upload folder] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J068l.jpg)

I am on ubuntu and nginx server

Thanks

I tried

- Folder permissions are set to 775 and file to 664
- Ownership of folders are www-data:www-data . I have tried with $user:www-data too
- Set app_url to the domain name

Comment: You need to provide more information about your setup.  This may be a question better suited for Superuser.com Please show images in text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.